# Is the order of adjectives correct in "a new sleeveless blue woolen jumper"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Is the order of adjectives in this sentence correct?

> I've just bought a new sleeveless blue woolen jumper.

Which category (perhaps size, shape, or something else) is "sleeveless" in? How does this fit with the traditional 'royal order of adjectives'?

> order .. relating to .... examples
>
> 1 opinion: *unusual, lovely, beautiful*
>
> 2 size: *big, small, tall*
>
> 3 physical quality: *thin, rough, untidy*
>
> 4 shape: *round, square, rectangular*
>
> 5 age: *young, old, youthful*
>
> 6 colour: *blue, red, pink*
>
> 7 origin: *Dutch, Japanese, Turkish*
>
> 8 material: *metal, wood, plastic*
>
> 9 type: *general-purpose, four-sided, U-shaped*
>
> 10 purpose: *cleaning, hammering, cooking*

[[Cambridge Dictionary, reformatted; note the  overlaps](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order)]

Comment: That "category sequence" is only a guide / tendency. It's unlikely (but *feasible*) that we'd put "sleeveless"*first* in this bizarre / contrived example, but it could reasonably go in any other position - the more contextually important you think *that* attribute is, the earlier you introduce it.

Comment: A coat without sleeves is not a coat. Maybe a **cloak** or a **mantle**.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: As an American, I'd call a coat without sleeves a *vest*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vest): 1c. an insulated sleeveless waist-length garment often worn under or in place of a coat.

Comment: A vest (UK waistcoat) is usually worn under a suit. It's not as long as a coat or a cloak. If the weather is wet and cold it'd be highly unusual for someone to say they're putting on their sleeveless coat or plain vest.

Comment: @PeterShor my point being is the OP shouldn't call a padded sleeveless garment a coat. It's not the best word in this case.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I agree that it's not the right word. But I don't think of either a *cloak* or a *mantle* as having armholes, whereas if somebody said *sleeveless coat* I would assume it had armholes. And the word for this type of garment in the U.S., if it's waist-length, is a *vest* (we do also call waistcoats *vests*, so without context there could easily be confusion).

Comment: Yes; according to the CD rankings, your example has a 5-9-6-8–ordered string. But I'd use it, or 5-6-9-8.

Comment: If it's American, it's "a collarless sleeveless dress, typically worn over a blouse" — in which case you can leave out *sleeveless*. If it's British, it would translate to *sweater vest* in American . . .

Comment: A vest (regardless of which side of the pond) is always sleeveless. And a jumper (sweater in AmE) that is sleeveless would be **a vest**. So, sleeveless vest is redundant and a jumper always has sleeves.

Comment: One additional ordering is possible:  alphabetical. *I've just bought a blue new sleeveless woolen jumper.*

Comment: @Lambie: Tell that to [Marks and Spencer](https://www.marksandspencer.com/us/pure-extra-fine-lambswool-sleeveless-jumper/p/P60548304.html).

Comment: @PeterShor Those are key words. British Vogue: sweater vest https://www.vogue.co.uk/fashion/article/sweater-vest-trend

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

Comment: @Lambie — [Here's a nice "Sleeveless jumper" featured in British Vogue.](https://www.vogue.co.uk/gallery/huxley-knitwear-label)

Comment: Personally if I hear "sleeveless" before "blue woolen" I will wonder "who cut off your sleeves? what a bastard!"  But I am David Crystal.

Answer (score 2):

As had been said, the "Royal Order of Adjectives" is guidance - not a rule.

I've just bought a jumper –> minimum information. It is not really "news".

The essence of the jumper is that it is sleeveless; it distinguishes it from all other styles of jumper -> I've just bought a {**sleeveless** jumper}.

The material is the next most important feature; it distinguishes it from all other materials from which jumpers are made: wool is warm - silk, not so much. -> I've just bought a {**woollen** sleeveless jumper}.

Then comes the colour -> I've just bought a new {**blue** woollen sleeveless jumper}. The colour is not very important. Would you have been more or less impressed had it been green or yellow? Probably not. The information is supplemental.

**New** is the least important. It is hardly worth saying (people rarely announce that they have bought second hand stuff) -> I've just bought a {**new** blue woollen sleeveless jumper}.

Answer (score 1):

English speakers don't naturally know the right place for *sleeveless* in adjective order (or maybe there isn't a unique place for this class of adjective). If you look at [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=black+sleeveless+silk%2C+sleeveless+black+silk%2C+black+silk+sleeveless&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), there are reasonable percentages of the three orders:

> sleeveless black silk,
> black sleeveless silk,
> black silk sleeveless,

even though you would never put *silk* before *black*.

As a native English speaker, I can say *sleeveless* definitely has to come after *age* and before *purpose* – you wouldn't say *sleeveless new dress* or *evening sleeveless dress*, those orders sound unnatural to me, and people don't seem to use them (see [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=new+sleeveless+dress%2Csleeveless+new+dress%2Cevening+sleeveless+dress%2Csleeveless+evening+dress&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)). However, any place between *age* and *purpose* appears to be acceptable.